# Upload file in android to server

Tags: android, upload

I need in my first android application, developed by Eclipse, upload file in android to remote server.

To do this I will use a web service in asp net.

In my android xml form I don't understand how do to for select a photo from the gallery and send the pic from the smartphone.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use multipart entity to upload a photo.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;

        photoHttpPost = new HttpPost(ADD_PHOTO_URL);


        try {
            String filePath = image;//imagepath here

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("refuges_id", new StringBody("" + refugeId));

            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);

            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", filePath));

            for (int index = 0; index < parameters.size(); index++) {
                if (parameters.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                    // If the key equals to "image", we use FileBody to transfer
                    // the data
                    entity.addPart(parameters.get(index).getName(),
                            new FileBody(new File(parameters.get(index)
                                    .getValue())));
                }
            }

            photoHttpPost.setEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Execute HTTP post Request
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            response = httpclient.execute(photoHttpPost);
            httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "timeout";
        } 

        // Execute HTTP Get Request
        if (httpEntity != null) {
            InputStream is;
            try {
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```